# python 3.6 pandas conditionally filling missing values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, null

If there is a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

users=pd.DataFrame(
                [
                {'id':1,'date':'01/01/2019', 'transaction_total':-1, 'balance_total':102},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/02/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/03/2019', 'transaction_total':np.nan, 'balance_total':np.nan},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/04/2019', 'transaction_total':np.nan, 'balance_total':np.nan},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/05/2019', 'transaction_total':-4, 'balance_total':np.nan},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/01/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':200},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/02/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/04/2019', 'transaction_total':np.nan, 'balance_total':np.nan},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/05/2019', 'transaction_total':-4, 'balance_total':np.nan}  
                ]
                )

print(users[['id','date','balance_total','transaction_total']])
```

Dataframe:

```
   id        date  balance_total  transaction_total
0   1  01/01/2019          102.0               -1.0
1   1  01/02/2019          100.0               -2.0
2   1  01/03/2019            NaN                NaN
3   1  01/04/2019            NaN                NaN
4   1  01/05/2019            NaN               -4.0
5   2  01/01/2019          200.0               -2.0
6   2  01/02/2019          100.0               -2.0
7   2  01/04/2019            NaN                NaN
8   2  01/05/2019            NaN               -4.0
```

How can i do the following?

If both of the transaction_total and balance_total are NaN, just fill in the last date's balance_total (e.g. in row 3 where id=1, since the user1's transaction_total and balance_total are NaN, fill in 100 from 01/02/2019.  The same will be row 4,  fill in 100 from 01/03/2019.)

If the transaction_total is NOT NaN, but balance_total is NaN, do the math of the previous date's balance_total+ the current row's date's transaction_total.

In user 1, 01/05/2019 as example: the balance total will be=100+(-4), where 100 is 01/04/2019's balance total, and (-4) is 01/05/2019's transaction total.

Desired output:

```
    id        date  balance_total  transaction_total
0   1  01/01/2019          102.0               -1.0
1   1  01/02/2019          100.0               -2.0
2   1  01/03/2019          100.0                NaN
3   1  01/04/2019          100.0                NaN
4   1  01/05/2019           96.0               -4.0
5   2  01/01/2019          200.0               -2.0
6   2  01/02/2019          100.0               -2.0
7   2  01/04/2019          100.0                NaN
8   2  01/05/2019           96.0               -4.0
```

here is my code but it doesn't work. I think i couldn't figure out how to do "if logic in pandas when a row is null, do something".

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():

    if(pd.isnull(row['transaction_total'] is True)): 

        if(pd.isnull(row['balance_total'] is True)): 

            df.loc[i,'transaction_total'] = df.loc[i-1,'transaction_total']
```

Could someone enlighten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, first create a dummy series with `ffill`, and then use `np.where`:

```
s = df["balance_total"].ffill()

df["balance_total"] = np.where(df["balance_total"].isnull()&df["transaction_total"].notnull(),
                               s.add(df["transaction_total"]), s)

print (df)

   id        date  transaction_total  balance_total
0   1  01/01/2019               -1.0          102.0
1   1  01/02/2019               -2.0          100.0
2   1  01/03/2019                NaN          100.0
3   1  01/04/2019                NaN          100.0
4   1  01/05/2019               -4.0           96.0
5   2  01/01/2019               -2.0          200.0
6   2  01/02/2019               -2.0          100.0
7   2  01/04/2019                NaN          100.0
8   2  01/05/2019               -4.0           96.0
```

Comment: Thank you @HenryYik

Comment: Hi @HenryYik i find there are cases where balance_total=0 & transaction_total is not null.  I do the following but it is given me the following error message: ```df["balance_total"] = np.where(
                                (df["balance_total"]==0 & df["transaction_total"].notnull() ) or 
                                (df["balance_total"].isnull() & df["transaction_total"].notnull() ),
                               s.add(df["transaction_total"]), s)``` ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().  Wonder if any thoughts? Thx

Comment: Use bitwise `|` instead of `or` @Chubaka

Comment: thank you @henry yik! | does work! wonder why in np.where | and or make differences?

Comment: As the error said, using normal logical operators is ambiguous for a Series (or np.array). You need to stick to bitwise operators for vectorized comparisons.